# Change REPL prompt from within the REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to change the prompt for Node's REPL with text given inside the REPL.

My original attempt was something like this.

```
import repl from 'repl'

let PROMPT = 'original > '

repl.start({
  ignoreUndefined: true,
  prompt: PROMPT,
  eval: (text, context, filename, callback) => {
    PROMPT = `${text} >`
    return callback()
  }
})
```

I realized this isn't gonna work because the prompt for the repl is set when the process starts.

I came up with something like this, which starts a new repl with a new prompt after ever entered command.

```
import repl from 'repl'

let PROMPT = 'original > '
let REPL = createRepl(PROMPT)

function createRepl (prompt) {
  return repl.start({
    ignoreUndefined: true,
    prompt: PROMPT,
    eval: (text, context, filename, callback) => {
      PROMPT = `${text.replace(/\n/, '')} >`
      REPL.close()
      REPL = createRepl(PROMPT)
    }
  })
}
```

This solution is almost there the issue is that the process is exiting when I close the original REPL.

I'm simply trying to change the REPL prompt from inside the script after the process starts. I'm open to any means to do this. Ideally the `prompt` prop took a function with the `prompt` argument and allowed you to set it from within the function, then I could use an event or something else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to call `repl.setPrompt('foo> ');` to change the prompt.

Comment: Why is this not documented in https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html ? Hmm it does not work for me anyways, `node --version` is `v10.11.0`

Comment: @masterxilo I don't know why it's not documented, but it definitely does still work. You have to use `repl.setPrompt()` where `repl` is the object returned by `require('repl').start()`.

Comment: `repl.start()` returns REPLServer, documented here: https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#class-replserver

Comment: can't see the doc reference

Comment: FWIW `REPLServer` instances inherit from `readline.Interface`, which is where [`setPrompt()`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlsetpromptprompt) is now documented.